# Production environment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To begin, I'm quite a newbie to Rails. I'm making a blog app, and when trying to run it on production, both ways:

```
rails s -e production
```

and

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the same error:

> => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on *http://0.0.0.0:3000*
>   => Call with -d to detach
>   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   Exiting
>   /home/loku/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-> resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
>   ...

My setup:

```
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]

Rails 3.2.8
```

database.yml:

```
development:    
  adapter: mysql2    
  encoding: utf8    
  reconnect: false    
  database: blogg_development    
  pool: 5    
  timeout: 5000    
  username: root    
  password: *** 
  host: localhost    

production:    
  adapter: mysql2       
  encoding: utf8    
  reconnect: false    
  database: blogg_production    
  pool: 5    
  timeout: 5000    
  username: root    
  password: ***    
  host: localhost
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-    rails.git'
  #gem 'actionpack', '~> 3.1.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :linux do
  gem 'libnotify'
end

group :darwin do
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false
  gem 'growl'
end
```

Comment: this will happen if you haven't specified mysql2 in your Gemfile. Can you post the contents of that file ?

Comment: Do you have a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable set?

Comment: I guess I haven't, how should it be then?

Comment: You don’t need a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. Looking at the Rails source it looks like it checks for it and uses it in preference to `database.yml`, so I thought it might be causing your problem. If you don’t have it set it must be something else.

Comment: One more blind shot : indentation in database.yml ? It should be one tab or two spaces , but consistent ...

Comment: No, I'm sure that tabs and spaces are fine in project, any other ideas?

Comment: maybe try to use other yaml engine ?

Comment: What is your production server?

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use webbrick in production.

Comment: What error do you get when you run bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate ?

Comment: Is this working on development on the same box? meaning that ***rails server*** works w/o specifiying the environment

Answer (score 4):

These are the things to consider

1. mysql2 in Gemfile (it is)
2. production environment defined in config/database.yml (it is)
   2.2 remove any other environments from your database.yml and leave production: only
3. Make sure it's properly indented (I think it is)
4. bundle install (to make sure you have the gems installed)
5. bundle show mysql2 to see the version and ensure it's installed
6. bundle exec rails s -e production    (make sure to use bundle exec)
7. if that doesn't work, I would look in config/environments/production.rb and ensure there isn't anything rare there.

Answer (score 2):

Basing on the source, there are only 2 possible explanations for the error you got. AdapterNotSpecified - Raised when adapter not specified on connection (or configuration file `config/database.yml` misses adapter field).

Did you copy and paste your database.yml file? If so, you might want to erase it and type them all again from scratch. Make sure indentation is consistent. Sometimes when copy and pasting, you also copy some hidden characters which get evaluated and cause problems in your code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please make doubly certain what Rumen Milushev suggested: YAML is very sensitive to indentation.

Try removing the `production:` part completely, rename `development:` to `production:` and try again.

If that works, validate your database.yml against a tool such as [yamllint.com](http://yamllint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Gemfile needs to specify the mysql gem. -- never mind I see that it does now.
2. You need to specify the db socket. Its not always in /tmp/mysql.sock sometimes its in /var... it depends on your install of mysql2

   **socket: /tmp/mysql.sock** needs to be a line in your database.yml production section

e.g.

```
production:    
  adapter: mysql2       
  encoding: utf8    
  reconnect: false    
  database: blogg_production    
  pool: 5    
  timeout: 5000    
  username: root    
  password: ***
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock    
  host: localhost
```

1. yml is funny about indenting. Double check that it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add a `production` group in your gemfile... Something like the following:

```
group :production do
    gem 'mysql2'
end
```

The run `bundle install` from the terminal and trying starting it all again.

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify all environments you forgot about test thats probably why the error is happening

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's not actually true.